# Как вставить код в сайт на WordPress сразу после поста, используя function.php

Tags: wordpress, комментарии

Мне нужно вставить комментарии ВК на сайт https://jetroots.com/ и убрать родные комментарии WP.
Сейчас я вставляю код ВК комменариев с помощью хука WP comment_form_before, но если убрать блок комментариве хуку просто некуда вставиться.

Код хука в function.php

```
add_action( 'comment_form_before', 'vk_comments', 10, 2 );
function vk_comments() {
   if ( is_single() ) {
      ?>
<!-- Put this div tag to the place, where the Comments block will be -->
<div id="vk_comments"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
VK.Widgets.Comments("vk_comments", {limit: 10, attach: false});
</script>

      <?php
   }
}
```

Поэтому я хочу привязать вывод не к блоку комментариев, а к посту (сразу после поста).

Вопрос в том, какой хук отвечает за вывод кода сразу после Wordpress поста?

Еще вопрос, если я хочу оставить родные комментарии и хочу сделать так чтобы комментарии ВК были выше не только формы комментаривем но и самих комментариев.
[image: блок комментаривев]

Как вставить код через function.php опять же сразу после поста?

Answer (score 1):

За вывод комментариев отвечает шаблон `comments.php`. Я думаю вы можете прямо в него добавить код куда вам надо. Если это **child**-тема, то вы можете просто скопировать файл `comments.php` из родительской и изменить его.

Comment: В принципе да! Это тоже решение! Но есть ли решение через `function.php`? Чтобы не создавать лишние файлы и не нагружать систему.

Comment: Одним файлом вы систему не нагрузите) Но посмотрите в сам файл и поищите там нужный хук, во многих темах делают такие. Так же можете посмотреть через какую функцию выводится ваши комментарии и посмотреть внутри ее нужный хук

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!